# Wpf usercontrol with parameterised constructor

Tags: wpf, user-controls, unity-container

We are using Microsoft Unity and dependency injection and so we have parametrised  constructor for the usercontrol. How to inject this dependency into usercontrol using XAML?

I have added the usercontrol in XAML as below.

```
xmlns:usrRefundArrivalProcessor="Ttl.Refunds.Wpf.Dashboad.Application.Usercontrols;assembly=Ttl.Refunds.Wpf.Dashboad.Application"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dependency injection does not imply parameterized constructors.  In fact, if you look at the samples that come with Unity, most of the dependency injection is done by properties with the [Dependency] attribute.

Unity works very well with XAML, but only if you don't use parameterized constructors.  Convert your UserControl to take its dependencies using properties with the [Dependency] attribute, and you can easily use XAML.

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
  [Dependency]
  public ISomething Something { get; set; }

  [Dependency]
  public IWhatever Whatever { get { return (IWhatever)GetValue(WhateverProperty); } set { SetValue(WhateverProperty, value); }
  public readonly DependencyProperty WhateverProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Whatever", typeof(IWhatever), typeof(MyUserControl));

  ...
}
```

Note that a [Dependency] property can be declared either as a DependencyProperty or as a plain CLR property, as shown above.  This sounds like confusing nomenclature but in practice it is very simple.

To specify the UnityContainer in XAML and get automatic configuration, just create an inherited attached property "UnityHelper.Container" whose PropertyChangedCallback simply calls BuildUp on the specified container and passes in the object's type and the object:

```
public class UnityHelper
{
  public static IUnityContainer GetContainer(DependencyObject obj) { return (IUnityContainer)obj.GetValue(ContainerProperty); }
  public static void SetContainer(DependencyObject obj, IUnityContainer value) { obj.SetValue(ContainerProperty, value); }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ContainerProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Container", typeof(IUnityContainer), typeof(UnityHelper), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
  {
    Inherits = true,
    PropertyChangedCallback = (obj, e) =>
    {
      var container = e.NewValue as IUnityContainer;
      if(container!=null)
      {
        var element = obj as FrameworkElement;
        container.BuildUp(obj.GetType(), obj, element==null ? null : element.Name);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Now you can assign a UnityContainer to your root window and your entire application will use it, for example you could do it in your window's constructor as follows:

```
UnityHelper.SetContainer(this, new UnityContainer() ...);
```

Or you can assign the unity container using XAML at any desired level of the tree:

```
<UserControl ...
  my:UnityHelper.Container="{DynamicResource MainUnityContainer}" />
```

Having said all that, I think you'll will find that WPF's advanced data binding features and resource dictionaries together eliminate 98% of the reasons why a person might want to use Unity in the first place.  You may find it better in the long run to move away from Unity and go with simple MVVM.  At the very least I would try pure MVVM on a test application to see how it works before developing much code relying on Unity for dependency injection.

Comment: it works, but when i hit the tab button from one of the text box it throws exception 

Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation+FocusVisualAdorner", name = "". Exception message is: The current build operation (build key Build Key[System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation+FocusVisualAdorner, null]) failed: Could not load type 'System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation' from assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. (Strategy type BuildPlanStrategy, index 5)

Comment: This answer helped me tremendously. I wish I could give more than +1. I've added this thread to "My Favorites", but that only credits the guy asking the original question. So, Thank you!

Comment: If you create an interface (say called IUnityElement) that you apply to all your UserControls or Controls you need unity to run against then in the 'if(container!=null)' line you can check if the obj parameter is of that interface e.g. 'if (container != null && obj is IUnityInject)'. This eliminates the the error Miral commented on above (I got a similar one from a different object and the performance issue ZeePrime's answer, as the BuildUp is only run on FrameworkElements you need it to.

Answer (score 0):

Seems rather easy. Why don't you simply add "a public parameterless constructor" to your `UserControl`? You may choose not to use it in your code directly but that is what the Designer is looking for. If you want to make sure it is never called in code, put [a check for presence of Designer](http://alanle.com/2009/02/10/design-time-check-for-wpf-and-silverlight/) and throw an exception if Designer is not detected.

Answer (score 0):

It works, but performance are quite bad when you use grids or complex WPF screens.
Inherits = true implies that all the GUI elements created will have the PropertyChangedCallback of the attached property called just after constructor, even if that specific GUI element doesn't need Unity at all.
And when you have grids, everytime a new row appears all the GUI elements are created on the fly, with that callback called.
this was killing performance of our grid, so we have had to remove UnityInjection done this way.

But nevertheless there are places where we need UnityInjection in codebehind, and we have not found a nice solution for this problem, even if we are using MVVM.
Some complex user control is designed using MVVM, where the ViewModel of the control is created by the codebehind of the control itself, that is created by the XAML that is using the control.
In this specific case the ViewModel of the control doesn't know anything (yet) about Unity, but we DO need unity Injection in it, for accessing external resources there registered.